# Placing arrays via JSON from MySql Database inside WP_User_Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm rather stuck on something. I'm trying to place an array of ids via JSON inside the `include` parameter of `WP_User_Query`.

My code is as follows:

```
public function get_following_ids( $user_id = 0 ) {

        $following = array();

            $existing = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT following FROM {$this->table} WHERE user_id = %d", absint( $user_id ) ) );

        $following = json_decode( $existing );

        return ( $following );

}
```

WP_User_Query code

```
public function author_following_list( $user_following_ids ) {      

        $args = array(
                ...
                'include'   => json_encode( $user_following_ids )               
            );      

        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );       

        $follow_users = $user_query->get_results();


        ob_start();  

        if ( ! empty( $follow_users ) ) {                   
            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {                 
                    ...
            } 
        } else {
            echo 'no users';
        }

        $content = ob_get_contents();
                   ob_end_clean();

        echo $content;  
    }
```

Then inside another function I use:

```
$following_ids      = $this->get_following_ids( $user_to_follow );

$this->author_following_list( $following_ids );
```

When I use `var_dump( $user_following_ids );` in `the author_following_list` function it says `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" }`
yet I get `'no users'` as output.

Can someone put me on the right track on solving this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't tested it, but maybe following helps:
don't do json_encode, since include parameter needs an array, and $user_following_ids is already an array :

```
$args = array(
                ...
            'include'   => $user_following_ids                
        );
```

in documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query it says:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'include' => array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) );
```